How do reductionist physicalist perceive social sciences?
For the reductionist naturalists, only physical sciences can describe reality (Shook 2011, 5):

Other kinds of naturalism do not agree with reductionist universalism and feel comfortable with permitting other scientific fields to describe reality with just as much legitimacy as physics. Because the biological and social sciences have traditionally used some methodological principles and modes of causality that depart from the physical sciences, many naturalists want to draw a line between trustworthy physical sciences (physics, chemistry, geosciences, astronomy, cosmology) and suspicious biological and social sciences.
The naturalists who would permit just the physical sciences to describe reality (“scientism”) form a separate camp from those naturalists who are comfortable with all of the physical, biological, and social sciences describing reality (“pluralism”).

So what are for reductionist naturalists fields like economy, sociology, linguistics, anthropology? They do not describe reality? They have nothing to do with Truth, and knowldege? If it is the case, then they should not exist?
References:
Shook, J. (2011). Varieties of twentieth century American naturalism. The Pluralist, 6(2), 1-17.

Reductionism only defends reductions "in principle". Social sciences provide high level descriptions that are perfectly legitimate and even unavoidable since a reduction to physics has not been achieved yet. And may even never be achievable due to practical intractability. They just do not "describe reality with as much legitimacy as physics" because they are not fundamental, i.e. use derivative terms with less metaphysical import.

@Conifold I feel Shook holds a less tolerant view about reductionist physicalists, he says later "Reductive Physicalism must demand complete submission to the principle of reductionist universalism from all other sciences, or else it must admit the superiority of Exclusivist Liberal Pluralism."

"Challenges to reductionism can arise from the natural sciences, such as biology or geology—the reduc- tive physicalist demands that these sciences’ entities and laws be reducible in principle to those of physics, but no one knows how to even attempt such a reduction."

This just amounts to insisting that high level laws "must be reducible in principle" to fundamental ones. It sounds big but amounts to almost nothing in practice, other than aspirationally. It provides a methodological motivation to look for lower level mechanisms underlying high level descriptions, which is not such a bad thing. The search for neural correlates of psychological phenomena is motivated by this sort of outlook, for example. And we know that thermodynamics reduces to statistical mechanics, but do not stop using reducible concepts like temperature and entropy.

@Conifold "since a reduction to physics has not been achieved yet. And may even never be achievable due to practical intractability." seems like a pragmatic argument, is it? So social sciences like linguistics or sociology exist because we have not been able yet to reduce syntactic rules or sociological phenomenon to physics? Pragmatically, we continue to do linguistics and social sciences until then (then which will probably never come)

It is a pragmatic argument, and it works regardless of whether reduction has been achieved, until then or after. Thermodynamics has been reduced to statistical mechanics, yet we continue to use it. Why? Because working with fundamental descriptions would be a waste of effort for many tasks at hand, even when it is feasible at all. Of course, they do provide more theoretical conceptual benefits.

I know as a programmer that all my work defining variables and algorithms reduces to millions of switches turning on and off. Which is why I wonder about people getting so picky over colors and fonts or wording. But I feel the same way about basically everything humans do.

@Conifold Why wouldn't you put that all those such valuable explanations in an answer (just a copy paste)? Would like to +1 and accept. Thank you so much.

What even is a "reductionist naturalist", like your quote only explains a "reductionist universalist" and ctrl+f doesn't show that term in his entire monogram.

The position that there exists a reduction (reductionism) doesn't preclude one from modelling things on a higher or more abstract level.

Most people should accept that a crowd is made up of / reduces to distinct humans and their interactions, without additional elements, yet we can still create models of crowds without having to model what every single actual person would do in that crowd.
Most people should accept that fluid reduces to elementary physical particles, but we can still create models of fluids without having to model every single physical particle.
We can also model crowds as fluids, interestingly enough, and astronomical objects can also be modelled as fluids.
And Scott's example: we accept that computers reduce to electricity moving through switches and transistors and capacitors and wires and such, yet we still model a computer's behaviour through high-level programming languages that abstracts those details away. On even higher levels, we can model computer networks or model behaviour of artificial intelligence or (as a developer or a player) model how characters in a video game might behave, without necessarily concerning ourselves with the low-level details of transistors and capacitors and such.

For all of the above models:

They model the objective behaviour of complex systems.
These systems reduce to their component parts.
The models don't concern themselves with the individual behaviour of every single component part.
The models are useful because complex systems with certain properties behave in consistent ways, as a result of the sum of the behaviours of the component parts.

For reductionism more broadly, the same idea applies. We are able to model things on a high level even if that ultimately reduces to some lower-level component parts. Those things aren't mutually exclusive.
Other people can debate whether these models are really "true", and what it even means for a model to be "true". But if a model accurately describes behaviour, then it is useful.

Shook apparently tries to categorize the variations of naturalism. First breaking it down in to 3 main contestants:
synoptic monoism: Mind and matter are just one thing either because there is only one of them being real and the other being a product of that or because there is a third thing that is real and the two are just different way of looking at that.
perspectival Realism: I'm still not sure I fully understand that one, but apparently it has to do with emergent naturalism. So complex structures can have properties that go beyond the sum of their parts. Which enables high level sciences to have their own atomic entities to which they reduce, but which cannot be described by in terms of the lower level sciences despite them consisting of parts of the lower level sciences. So idk if you run your meal through mass spectrometry you can tell all that's inside of it, but you don't know how the specific combination was composed and what properties (like taste, texture, etc) it had. Or maybe the difference between a living person and a corpse, which might be technically identical but still vastly different.
And last but not least Scientific Exclusivism: Which posits that if we assumed we'd "played through science" and have actually perfected it, there would be nothing real outside of that. There's also the version that we're already there, but that's unlikely given all the open questions, the falsifications and revisions of the theories in the past and often the definition of science via the updating process.
On top of that he distinguishes between "narrow", "fitting" and "broad" naturalism. So narrow is the content of what science can explain already. Fitting is narrow plus things that can be hypothetically reduced what science can explain. And broad is fitting plus things that can be hypothesized only referencing things which can be described by science.
And on top of that he asks the question how many sciences are needed and distinguishes between physics (as the most fundamental), physical sciences (direct descendants and relatives of physics. He mentions stuff that is already subsumed by physics or chemistry which is the closest relative to physics within the natural sciences) and lots more sciences (the whole rest,. biology, social sciences and whatnot). Which he categorizes as "physicalism, scientism and pluralism".
Then he combines the number of sciences with the "narrow", "fitting" and "broad". And uses the prefix eliminative for 1 science, reductive for 2 (or derived sciences) and liberal for lots of further derived sciences.
And then he looks at the 27 combinations ((syn. mono., persp. real, sci. excl.) x (eliminative, reductive, liberal) x (physicalism, scientism. Pluralism). And narrows them down to 7 viable option.
Though after summarizing the paper thus far, let's get to the actual question :)
So first of all what is reductive naturalism? Well he doesn't really use that as a distinct category, so either you refer to "reductive universalism" which is mention in the quote and would down the line result in "eliminative physicalism", so the idea that everything is explainable by the most fundamental level of science (he calls it physics, but really just what is the most fundamental) and only by that. So essentially other phenomena would be an illusion, like how you would see patterns in white noise while what is really happening is just random fluctuation.
Or reductive naturalism refers to the group of the 9 reductive naturalism out of the 27 proposed naturalisms, out of which he outright rejects 7, ranks 1 as poor and has "reductive physicalism" as the last one standing. Now if I understand that one correctly, then it's a variation of there is only 1 science. So it's some sort of an upwards causality. So the fundamental physics allows for the formation of atoms, which form molecules which form cells, which form organism, which interact with each other, but technically physics provides the building blocks of reality and the others are just stacking these blocks higher and higher, but can ultimately be reduced to the most fundamental. So a sociologist is just a very very very very specialized physicist.
